# PrimeFaces calendars and mindate attribute

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, calendar

I'm working with primefaces calendar component. I have two calendar components, and I want the mindate attribute of the second calendar is updated with the date of the first calendar.

```
<p:calendar id="fromDate" effect="drop" navigator="true" value="#{myBean.fromDate}">
 <f:ajax event="dateSelect" execute="@this" render="toDate"/>
</p:calendar>   

<p:calendar id="toDate" effect="drop" navigator="true" mindate="#{myBean.fromDate}"/>
```

It works properly excepts when in the first calendar there is a date and then the user delete this date. The second calendar is not rendered again, and it has a mindate value when it should not because the user delete the date of the first calendar.

Comment: When you say "the user deletes this date", is he manually deleting the date? As in, you're accepting user input? If that's the case, then you might also want to handle the `change` event.

Comment: Yes, I'm accepting user input. When a user delete the date from the input field I'm expecting that the second calendar updates with no mindate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the solution:

```
<p:calendar id="fromDate" effect="drop" navigator="true" value="#{myBean.fromDate}">
  <f:ajax event="dateSelect" execute="@this" render="toDate"/>
  <f:ajax event="change" execute="@this" render="toDate" />
</p:calendar>   

<p:calendar id="toDate" effect="drop" navigator="true" mindate="#{myBean.fromDate}"/>
```

It was necessary to add a second ajax tag.

The first one is needed when the user change the date picking a date from the calendar.
The second one is needed when the user change the date writing in the input field.

When user remove the date from the input field the second ajax tag updates the mindate of the second calendar.

Comment: Glad my comment helped.